# 'closeapp' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, arduino

Hello i change the usbdriveby project.
It is just to just the keyboard for fun
The error message app :'closeapp' was not declared in this scope.
Here is the code :

```
#if defined(CORE_TEENSY)
#define LED_PIN 11
#else
#define LED_PIN 13
#endif
void setup() {
delay(800);

  openapp("Terminal");
  typeln("screen -S SYSTEMUpdater");
  typeln("say dont use unknown usb sticks because its not safe.");
  closeapp;
}
void openapp(String app)
{
  cmd(KEY_SPACE);
  typeln(app);
}
void typeln(String chars)
{
  Keyboard.print(chars);
  delay(ds);
  Keyboard.println("");
  delay(ds * 4);
}
void closeapp
{
  cmd(KEY_Q);
}
void k(int key)
{
  Keyboard.set_key1(key);
  Keyboard.send_now();
  delay(ds/2);

  Keyboard.set_key1(0);
  Keyboard.send_now();
  delay(ds/2);
}

void mod(int mod, int key)
{
  Keyboard.set_modifier(mod);
  Keyboard.send_now();
  Keyboard.set_key1(key);
  Keyboard.send_now();
  delay(ds);

  Keyboard.set_modifier(0);
  Keyboard.set_key1(0);
  Keyboard.send_now();
  delay(ds);
}

void ctrl(int key)
{
  mod(MODIFIERKEY_CTRL, key);
}

void cmd(int key)
{
  mod(MODIFIERKEY_GUI, key);
}

void shift(int key)
{
  mod(MODIFIERKEY_SHIFT, key);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(ds/2);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  delay(ds/2);
}
```

I searched for the same error but I am pretty sure that  I made an error in the writing.

Comment: `void closeapp {` --> `void closeapp (void) {` and `closeapp;` --> `closeapp();` VTC as minor.

Answer (score 1):

Function `closeapp` is not syntactically valid in C language.
It should be something like:

```
void closeapp()
{
  cmd(KEY_Q);
}
```

Moreover function call should be something like:

```
closeapp();
```

to be syntactically valid.

The last point is, that you shouldn't call function before its implementation. It means either you will provide prototype or put its definition before it's really called.

EDIT FYI: Statement `closeapp;` is syntactically valid, but it is empty instruction just like `42;`. Literally it is the address of `closeapp` function, so basically just a number.

Comment: Even then, the compiler will probably complain about not having a visible declaration of `closeapp()` at the time it is called from `setup()`.

Comment: Your pre-edit version was better. The result of writing `closeapp;` is _syntactically_ valid but not **semantically** valid, i.e. it's clearly not what the OP wants. It maps to a no-op evaluation of the address of the function. Also, further to my point about the visible declaration, it gets worse: the compiler might error out, **or** it might just warn (if you have warnings on, which we all do, right?) that it's going to use a different, assumed signature - which will lead to undefined behaviour if it mismatches... as it probably will.

Comment: Yup, I was editing at the time. Well, I also assume that compiler removes and optimize closeapp; statement by default, as you said it's noop.

Just to be precise: I meant it is not syntactically valid **function call**, but it's true that it is syntactically valid statement.